# Can't post answer because of malformed code, but code seems well formed

Tags: support, code-formatting, validation

I am trying to post answer to a question, but I fail validation for malformed code.

## What I've tried so far:

- Paste markdown into text editor
- Turn on visible white space and count the spaces, carriage returns etc
- Remove all the code references

So far I am having no luck. **Any other ideas?**

- **How do I test my markdown if it's failing validation?**

Comment: Are you indenting the code properly? Are you ensuring there is a whole empty line between any none-code and code lines?

Comment: I thought so. Hence I turned on the "visible white space" to count and make sure

Comment: Are there exotic characters in it? Sometimes these trip up the spam filter.

Comment: No exotic chars that I can see. it seems like plain old text markdown in a basic text editor. I tried removing all markdown formatting and still have a validation failure. I feel like i'm at the point of pasting line by line to figure out which block is causing the failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to test things out - play around with formatting etc, use the sandbox question:

[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Are you sure this is the right place? Looking through some of the downvoted answers, we see it's people testing to see what is working. Is this sandbox not more specifically for formatting experiments as opposed to debugging markdown?

Comment: It is for both.